# React: Prevent Right Click from focusing an otherwise focusable element

Tags: reactjs, focus, dom-events

I know this seems simple, and the first instinct is going to be to suggest something like `preventDefault` in mousedown event. That is not what this question is.

In React, I just want to have an `input` that when `Left Clicked` receives its focus as normal, and when `Right Clicked` does not receive focus.

I can find no combination of event handlers or event manipulation that will allow this (in chrome at least). I'm tempted to put event handlers outside of the React DOM and get surgical with disabling higher up in the capture phase before react gets involved, but I'm just hoping I'm missing something and somebody can see something obvious I'm missing.

Here's various combinations of "everything" I've thrown at it. Synthetic event standard prevention, nativeEvent prevention, every variation of capture and bubble phase, etc. Event with all of the event handlers below, I can prevent Left Click from setting focus, but still Right Click sets focus on the input.

```
//React v16.12.0
function killEvent (e: React.SomeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
    //[Neither above nor below seems to work]
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

<input
    onContextMenuCapture={killEvent}
    onContextMenu={killEvent}
    onClick={killEvent}
    onClickCapture={killEvent}
    onAuxClick={killEvent}
    onAuxClickCapture={killEvent}
    onPointerDown={killEvent}
    onPointerDownCapture={killEvent}
    onMouseDownCapture={killEvent}
    onMouseDown={killEvent}
    onFocusCapture={killEvent}
    onFocus={killEvent}
/>
```

Comment: to better understand the situation, can you please give me example of this usage, because right now I cannot wrap my head around it. I think example usage would be great for other to understand this too

Comment: Left click a thing. Have it focus. Right click the same thing, prevent it from getting focus.

Comment: ok you can use "oncontextmenu" event for capturing right click, and then rest should be straight forward

Comment: You see in my question I have onContextMenu in there? Stopping propagation and preventing default in the context menu event, both referencing the native and the synthetic, does not prevent focus being. Are you commenting with understanding of the react synthetic event system?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, sorry I missed the oncontextmenu being used, I used the same thing in local and I get your point, but using prevent event for right click is preventing the browser right click to show up, which is working only with the use of e.nativeEvent.preventDefault(); , question is to disable the field when right click, so why dont you just use  e.target.disabled = true; and then false on right click or something similar because as I said prevent default is working as it is suppose to

 killEvent = e => {
    e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
    e.target.disabled = true;
  };

Comment: @CooperBuckingham Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution

Capture on mouse down

```
 <input onMouseDown={this.killEvent} />
```

then check which button is clicked

```
 killEvent = e => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.which === 3) {
      e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Negative voter should give a reason behind negative vote !!

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the questioner already tried `evt.nativeEvent.preventDefault()` and you just suggested it, but inside a conditional.